# Neo4j Filter the status

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j DB. in neo4j all persons can post the images as a `public` or `private`. in this case I want to fetch all `public` posts. and also the current user `private` and `public` posts.

Thanks, in advance.

[image: Graph]

Comment: Neo4j testing console for the given scenario http://console.neo4j.org/?id=gg1v1c 

You may need to seperate the post nodes with type to differentiate between public and private then it is easy to filter it by status. 

*Cypher Query:*
`Match (p:Person)-[:POST_THE]->(post:Post) WHERE post.type='public' return p,post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you have `Person` and `Post` nodes, and that `Post` nodes have the `isPrivate` boolean property.

1. Fetch all public posts:

   ```
   MATCH (post:Post)
   WHERE NOT post.isPrivate
   RETURN post
   ```
2. Fetch a user's private and public posts (in separate lists):

   ```
   MATCH (person:Person)-[:POST_THE]->(post)
   WHERE person.id = 123
   WITH person, COLLECT(post) AS posts
   RETURN
     person,
     [p IN posts WHERE p.isPrivate | p] AS privatePosts,
     [p IN posts WHERE NOT p.isPrivate | p] AS publicPosts
   ```